# How to setup a react state to use a list of a custom type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

So I'm trying to find a way to update a react component when a list of results gets updated. The results are being displayed with a `list.map` statement. The obvious answer seems to be to change the variable to a react state however I can't find the correct syntax to initialize the state to an empty list of a custom type and still be able to map the results.

current working example that doesn't update the page:

```
var results: customType[] = [];

results.append(CustomTypeItem)

// API call that updates results when search is pressed

return({results.map((item, index) => (
   <Entry value={item} key={index} />
))});
```

What I've tried

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

setResults([CustomTypeItem]) // throws error that type is not assignable to never
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `const [list, setList] = useState<IType[]>([])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [results, setResults] = useState<any[]>([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set an empty array as the default value of your state

```
const [list, setList] = useState([])
```

and then when you update the list state with setList(), your component will auto re-rendered
to update the list's element, you can use [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/)'s functions like update or remove

Comment: I tried this however if I try to set the list to a list of a custom type, it throws errors that the types don't match

Comment: so you cant set the type for the init array, like `useState<CustomType []>([])`

Comment: like @hellogoodnight's answer, you can try it